# Por que "this.lista" está undefined?

Tags: javascript

[image]
[image]

Não entendi por que o `this.lista` está undefined na linha 7, alguém pode me explicar?

Quero somente a explicação, sei que se eu substituir, na linha 13, `.onclick = lista.add` por `.onclick = function(){ lista.add(); }`  funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` em JavaScript é contextual.

Quando a função `add` é invocada como método de um objeto, como é o caso de `lista.add`, `this` se refere ao objeto, ou seja, `this` é `lista`.

Quando `add` é invocado dentro do contexto `onclick` de um elemento, `this` se refere ao elemento, ou seja, `this` é `botao`.

Como você está passando apenas a referência da função para o seu elemento, a função é invocada no contexto do elemento. `this` irá se referir a `botao`, e `botao` não possui a propriedade `lista`, por isso você recebe o erro `não é possível ler a propriedade 'push' de undefined`, pois ao buscar a propriedade `lista` de `botao` você recebe `undefined`, e ao invocar `push` em `undefined`, você recebe um erro.